# base.Method() with multiple levels of inheritance not being called?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, base-class

I've searched and not been able to find any solution to my problem. My scenario is very simple:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void MethodOne()
    {
       Console.log( "A" ); 
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void MethodOne()
    {
        base.MethodOne();
        Console.log( "B" );
    }
}

public class C : B
{
    public override void MethodOne()
    {
        base.MethodOne();
        Console.log( "C" );
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is have an instance of class C (we'll name it 'instanceC') call both the overridden method of its parent, and its grandparent. So I'd expect this:

```
instanceC.MethodOne();
// Output:
// "A"
// "B"
// "C"
```

But instead am getting this:

```
instanceC.MethodOne();
// Output
// "A"
// "C"
```

with class B's method being skipped over. Is this not possible? I thought this is the whole point of inheritance/polymorphism. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure C is derived from B and not A?

Comment: Why would C ovveride from B? you want it to inherit from A.

Comment: Your example works as expected for me and prints 'A B C'

Comment: Same for me, your example works, there must be something missing or wrong with your original code

Comment: @Derek If you need some behavior from B to be performed but you need additional behavior added before or after the call. I once had to override FileStream due to XmlReader.Parse was blowing up on invalid ASCII characters. I was able to override GetBytes, call `base.GetBytes` to get the result from FileStream, change the invalid values to a replacement character, then pass it along to `XmlReader.Create`

Comment: I am going to have to give a -1, from what the button says "You did not show research effort", update your code to re-create whatever problem you are having and I will remove it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your example works as expected for me.  I see A B C.  I think your most likely issue is that C doesn't extend B.  However, let me suggest an arguably safer pattern while we're on the subject.  You seem to want all overrides of MethodOne to execute code from their base classes.  Great, inheritance is a good pattern for this.  However, with this pattern you cannot force inheritors to execute the base logic because you cannot force them to call `base.MethodOne()`.  Even if they do call`base.MethodOne()`, you cannot ensure the order of the logic.  Will they call `base.MethodOne()` at the beginning of the method, middle of the method, or end of the method?  Often, in these types of patterns you want sub classes to execute all the base logic at the beginning of the function.  The following pattern forces inheritors to execute base logic in the order base classes expect.  It's technically less flexible but safer because inheritors must extend the base classes in a way that the base classes specify.

```
public class A
{
    //Don't make this method virtual because you don't actually want inheritors 
    //to be able to override this functionality.  Instead, you want inheritors
    //to be able to append to this functionality.
    public void MethodOne()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "A" ); 
        MethodToBeOverriddenOne();
    }
    //Expose a place where inheritors can add extra functionality
    protected virtual void MethodToBeOverriddenOne() { }      
}

public class B : A
{
    //Seal the method because you don't actually want inheritors 
    //to be able to override this functionality.  Instead, you want inheritors
    //to be able to append to this functionality.
    protected sealed override void MethodToBeOverriddenOne()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
        MethodToBeOverriddenTwo();
    }
    //Expose a place where inheritors can add extra functionality
    protected virtual void MethodToBeOverriddenTwo() { }  
}

public class C : B
{
    protected sealed override void MethodToBeOverriddenTwo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the other as it clearly shows how to ensure the base methods are always called.  No idea why it was downvoted.

Comment: I am running on little sleep and you guys were right; C was foolishly extending A instead of C. So while that was indeed the problem, I actually do think this is a better solution, and am having good results. Thank you!

Comment: Wasn't me downvoting, I thought it was better than mine too and gave it a +1

Comment: Pretty old question I know, but I just wanted to add that this is obviously a nice pattern if that's what you want. If you need the client to be able to disable base class functionality (and actually override it), this is not the way to go. Of course, then you'd be calling `base.MethodOne()` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

The example you posted works perfectly, whatever you are doing in your actual code is different than what you posted.

[Here is your code running on ideone](http://ideone.com/WTmD64) working as exactly like you wanted.

```
using System;

public class Test
{
        public static void Main()
        {
                var c = new C();
                c.MethodOne();
        }
}

public class A
{
    public virtual void MethodOne()
    {
       Console.WriteLine( "A" ); 
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void MethodOne()
    {
        base.MethodOne();
        Console.WriteLine( "B" );
    }
}

public class C : B
{
    public override void MethodOne()
    {
        base.MethodOne();
        Console.WriteLine( "C" );
    }
}
```